# Most efficient way to store 5 attributes

Tags: java

So I'm trying to store 5 attributes of an object, which are 5 different integers.

What would be the best way to store these?  I was thinking of arrays, but arrays aren't flexible. I also need to be able to retrieve all 5 attributes, so arrays probably won't work  well.

Here's some background if it helps: I am currently making a game similar to Terraria (or Minecraft in 2D).
I wanted to store where the object is on the `map(x,y)`, where it is on the screen at the part of the `map(x,y)`, and what type of object it is.

Comment: What's wrong with instance variables?

Comment: If you're eliminating arrays b/c they aren't "flexible" then you probably need to be more specific about how you judge the most efficient solution.

Comment: @PaulR hi, probably by neatness, expandability, and how many variables i'll need.

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.awt.Point

public class MyClass {
    private Point pointOnMap;
    private Point pointOnScreen;
    // ... 
}
```

The `Point` class binds x & y values into a single object (which makes sense) and gives you useful, basic methods it sounds like you'll need, such as `translate` and `distance`.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html

Comment: I'd add an enum for the object type.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to predict what is the most efficient way to store the attributes without seeing all of your code.  (And I for one don't want to :-))  Second, you haven't clearly explained what you are optimizing for.  Speed?  Memory usage?  Minimization of GC pauses?

However, this smells of premature optimization.  Wasting lost of time trying to optimize performance on something that hasn't been built, and without any evidence that the performance of this part the codebase is going to be significant.

My advice would be:

1. Pick a simple design and implement it; e.g. 5 `private int` variables with getters and setters.  If that is *inconvenient*, then choose a more convenient API.
2. Complete the program.
3. Get it working.
4. Benchmark it.  Does it run fast enough?  If yes, stop.
5. Profile it.  Pick the biggest performance hotspot and optimize that.
6. Rerun the benchmarking and profile to check that your optimization *has made things faster*.  If yes, then "commit" it.  If not then back it out.
7. Go to step 4.

Comment: Hi! actually im trying to make it efficient as in organizing and coding =)problem with int is that since we can create an infinite amount of object in our game, there will be a ginormous mess of ints, and since we can't use a variable to determine the name of a int (eg. int a+b blah blah blah when a and b are variables and the name is to be ab). We will then have problem trying to identify which variable is for each item

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest HashMap where key can be `objectId-attributeName` and value will be `integer` value as you have to do retrieval based on key. This will be `O(1)` operation

Comment: oh that sounds good! exactly what im looking for. what class is this?